# How to reinitialize device, connected with USB to android device with code?

Tags: android, xamarin, usb

I am developing application with Xamarin.Forms for smart POS terminal Tianyu P20L (Android 7).

By tech requirements for this application we have e-token, that should be always connected to terminal with USB. Terminal charges with charging pad (terminal has 2 pins on its back panel for charging). Every time we take off the terminal from charging pad, it looses the connection with e-token.  `UsbManager.DeviceList` returns an empty collection.

There are 2 ways to reestablish connection:

1. place terminal back to charging pad
2. reconnect token physically

but none of these suits us, because e-token should be always connected to terminal and we can not keep the terminal on the charging pad always.

Is there a way to reinitialize USB connection with code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The e-Token is always directly connected to the USB (OTG) peripheral port on the P20L?

Comment: Yes, and it can not be physically disconnected and connected again due to P20L specific case design

Comment: Do you receive a disconnect intent when removing the POS from the charger?

Comment: Yes, my BroadcastReceiver works well